# How to replace SQL "WITH" with Big Query Materialized View

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata, bq, exploratory-data-analysis

I'm attempting to perform some exploratory data analysis on Big Query but am running into problems. I am fairly underdeveloped in my SQL knowledge and even more so with regards to BQ. This piece of code:

```
DECLARE columns ARRAY<STRING>;
DECLARE query STRING;
SET columns = (
  WITH all_columns AS (
    SELECT column_name
    FROM `your-client.staging.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
    WHERE table_name = 'churn'
  )
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG((column_name) ) AS columns
  FROM all_columns
);

SET query = (select STRING_AGG('(select count(distinct '||x||')  from `your-client.staging.churn`) '||x ) AS string_agg from unnest(columns) x );
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
"SELECT  "|| query
;
```

is the piece I'm trying to use. It runs on Kaggle's churn dataset (14 columns and 10k rows) but mine is significantly bigger (145 columns and ~72m) rows. Despite it being quite sparsely populated, I am getting the following error:

```
Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex.. at [1:1]
```

I have heard that a good way to sort this out is by using materialized views to create temporary tables instead of using the `WITH` but I have no clue where to start.

Any help on this or any other solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I could see that `count(distinct)` without a `group by` would be computationally expensive.  Does the query run independently of the `execute immediate`?

Comment: Not too sure unfortunately, found a completely different way of sorting it. Thanks for the help and apologies for the late reply!